# How can i create an grpc client not in controller using nest.js

Tags: grpc, nestjs

follow the [sample](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/04-grpc/src/hero/hero.controller.ts) of nest.js, all the thing work well.
try to move grpc client out of Controller， get an error： ‘Cannot read property 'getService' of null’。 it look like the client did not init。
using the code as follow：

```js
export class GrpcClient {

  @Client(GRPC_OPTIONS.DASHBOARD)
  private static dashBoardClient: ClientGrpc
  public static dashBoardService

  static async initService() {
    this.dashBoardService = this.dashBoardClient.getService<any>(GRPC_SERVICE.DASHBOARD)
  }
  
}

GrpcClient.initService()
```

Is it the client only can init in Controller??